# How to manage functions to use beatiful soup efficiently

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to **web-scrape** Bulbapedia (wiki about Pokemons) to create some kind of Pokedex in Python using BeaufiulSoup4. I'm wondering how to create functions that will suck the data from html.

I've got the initial function that takes url and change it to soup object:

```
def urlToSoup(url):
    website = requests.get(url)   
    soup = BeautifulSoup(website.text,'html.parser')
    return soup
```

What's next - I want to get pokemon details from given website. Let's say I've got Bulbasaur. I can create one huge function to get those details and return pandas series:

```
def getPokemonDetails(pokemon):
    
    #Get pokemon HTML
    URL = 'https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/'+pokemon+'_(Pok%C3%A9mon)'
    soup = urlToSoup(URL)
    
    #Get pokemon number
    number = int(soup.select('big>a[title="List of Pokémon by National Pokédex number"]')[0].text[1:])

    #Get pokemon name
    name = soup.select('big>b')[0].text
    .
    .
    .
return pd.Series(
        data=[
            number,
            name,
            category,
            name_JP,
            ...
            ],
        index=[
            'number',
            'name',
            'category',
            'japanese_name',
            ...
            ]
    )
```

Dots just tell you that there is more code, but that's not the point. Above you see how I currently keep my code. In my feelings the form is badly, because every single functionality, like "Get poemon number", "Get poekmon name" etc should be handled by different functions.

My first idea was to create one function for each functionality where as an argument you pass pokemon name, like "Bulbasaur". The issue here is that when I want to gather all informations about given pokemon, each function will reqeest HTML, parse it to soup and that's time consuming. Get name, number, evoultion, height etc. will run urlToSoup function which is inefficient.

```
def getNumber(pokemon)
    soup = urlToSoup(https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/'+pokemon+'_(Pok%C3%A9mon))
    somecodetogetnumber
    return number

def getName(pokemon)
    soup = urlToSoup(https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/'+pokemon+'_(Pok%C3%A9mon))
    somecodetogetname
    return name
.
.
.
```

So I thought that insted of passing pokemon name and repeatedly call "urlToSoup" function I will call it once to get soup for given poemon and pass this as an argument to getName, getNumber, getWeight etc.

```
def getNumber(pokemon_soup)
    somecodetogetnumber
    return number

def getName(pokemon_soup)
    somecodetogetname
    return name
.
.
.

def getPokemonDetails(pokemon)
    URL = 'https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/'+pokemon+'_(Pok%C3%A9mon)'
    soup = urlToSoup(URL)

    number = getNumber(soup)
    name = getName(soup)
```

But the question is - if I create soup for given pokemon and pass it as an argument to function, will the functions make a copy of soup to work with or there will be only one Bulbasaur soup that all function will work on (assuming I pass this Bulbasaur soup as argument). In kinda other words - if I create soup for given pokemon and give it to function, is it going to pass by reference to soup or make a copy? In second case it's still ineffective.

I hope you see clearly what are my ideas and can advice me what to do.

Comment: Web scraping using Beautiful Soup requires different script and logic for different websites based on the information we are trying to scrape. It will be great if you can specify what all you require and exact url for this page.

Comment: Here is example of URL https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Bulbasaur_(Pok%C3%A9mon), altough keep in mind that I will run through all 900 URLs with pokemons. Gladly the structure for every URL is the same. Program will look at different places like the table where pokemon types are, number, weight etc. That's why I think I should keep these in different functions

Answer (score 0):

Function will not create copy if given soup as argument, consider following simple example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
def change_soup_name(s, n):
    s.name = n
soup = BeautifulSoup('<html><head></head><body></body></html>', 'html.parser')
print(soup.name)
change_soup_name(soup, '[newname]')
print(soup.name)
```

output

```
[document]
[newname]
```

Comment: So it seems I can use functions by passing soup :) Thank you